# Plotting of grouped data as line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot values by `duration` grouped by `id` and `date` from a table like this:

| id | date | duration | val1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2020-06-01 | 0:00:00 | 84.0 |
| 1234 | 2020-06-01 | 0:00:01 | 86.0 |

I use the following code for a sample of the data:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,8))
for key, grp in df_df_obj_dur.groupby(['id', 'date']):
    ax.plot(grp['duration'], grp['val1'])

ax.set_xticks([])
plt.xlabel('Duration')
plt.ylabel('Heart Rate')
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately this leads to the following result where the data points of the pink id/date-group seem to jump in x-axis which is quite confusing for me:
[image]

Comment: Do the groups have gaps? Is the data sorted?

Comment: No there are none. But the duration of the groups is not equal.

Comment: How many groups are there? Your code doesn't show you setting the color, yet I see pink and brown plots, which come later in the tab-10 sequence. And if you aren't setting the colors, the jumps in the plot show that (1) the data is unordered and (2) there are gaps.

Comment: @jared color is set by default. What do you mean by tab-10 sequence? Even if there were gaps, wouldn't the line direct to the last data point with the highest duration so far?

Comment: In matplotlib, if you let it choose the line color and repeatedly call `plot`, the lines will be colored in order of the tab-10 color sequence (see the sequence [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html#qualitative)). Your plot shows brown and pink, which are the sixth and seventh colors in the sequence, respectively. That seems to imply you have 5 other lines that are either not shown or being plotted over. And I don't know what you're saying about how the line would "direct to the last data point with the highest duration so far".

Comment: If you have gaps or unordered data, `plt.plot` will happily draw a straight line connecting those points, even if they are far from each other. That seems to be what is happening in your picture.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to recreate your problem without your data and data loading.
However, as comments suggest, the problem might be, that your data is not properly sorted, and contains gaps, which is why you could see the straight line connecting dots.

I tried to reproduce your problem with sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[1234, '2020-06-01', 1, 84.0],
    [1234, '2020-06-01', 2, 86.0],
    [1234, '2020-06-01', 3, 88.0],
    [1234, '2020-06-01', 4, 90.0],
    [1234, '2020-06-01', 5, 91.0],
    [1234, '2020-06-01', 6, 94.0],
    [1234, '2020-06-01', 6, 80.0],
    [1234, '2020-06-01', 7, 98.0],
    [1234, '2020-06-01', 8, 100.0],
    [1234, '2020-06-01', 9, 102.0],
    [1235, '2020-06-01', 1, 74.0],
    [1235, '2020-06-01', 3, 76.0],
    [1235, '2020-06-01', 4, 98.0],
    [1235, '2020-06-01', 5, 104.0],
    [1235, '2020-06-01', 6, 96.0],
    [1235, '2020-06-01', 7, 84.0],
    [1235, '2020-06-01', 8, 60.0],
    [1235, '2020-06-01', 9, 99.0],
    [1235, '2020-06-01', 10, 71.0],
    [1235, '2020-06-01', 15, 104.0],
],columns=['id', 'date', 'duration', 'val1'])
```

I now shuffled the data.

In the plot to the left I just used your code to reproduce a plot. as you can see, it is all random.

In the plot to left, I sorted the data again (df.sort_values(['id', 'date', 'duration']) before grouping it.
The plot now looks like intended.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20,8))

df = df.sample(frac = 1)

for key, grp in df.groupby(['id', 'date']):
    ax[0].plot(grp['duration'], grp['val1'], label = key)
    ax[0].legend()

for key, grp in df.sort_values(['id', 'date', 'duration']).groupby(['id', 'date']):
    ax[1].plot(grp['duration'], grp['val1'], label = key)
    ax[1].legend()
    
ax[0].set_xticks([])
ax[1].set_xticks([])
ax[0].set_xlabel('Duration')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Heart Rate')
ax[1].set_xlabel('Duration')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Heart Rate')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

key0 = "a a a a b b b b".split()
key1 = "0 0 1 1".split() * 2
X = range(len(key0))?
Y = [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2]
toPlotR = pd.DataFrame({"key0": key0, "key1": key1, "X": X, "Y": Y})
toPlotR["prettyLabel"] = ["%s%s" %(key0, key1) for (key0, key1) \
    in zip(toPlotR["key0"], toPlotR["key1"])]
print (toPlotR.head(3).to_markdown(index=False))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
labelL = list(set(toPlotR["prettyLabel"]))
labelL.sort()
for label in labelL:
  tempR = toPlotR.query("prettyLabel == '%s'" %label)
  tempR.plot("X", "Y", label=label, ax=ax)
```

Comment: This does not work and is even slower than my code.

Comment: @fid it is strange to see a plot be slow. I wonder if there is something interesting about your data that makes code not work as expected. If you look at only your first 100 rows, does it work?